# Как сделать вычисления и сгруппировать по индексу?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, анализ-данных

Загружаю файл, делаю индексом одну из колонок - `СубконтоДт1`. Необходимо сгруппировать по `СубконтоДт1`, сделать вычисления и вывести.

Исходная таблица:

```
СубконтоДт1            Период                 СубконтоДт1       Сумма                      Цена
Утеплитель            2018-09-21               ФОРПОСТ          16193.90                1124.58
Утеплитель             2018-07-12              ФОРПОСТ          15559.32                1296.61
Утеплитель             2019-09-13              ФОРПОСТ          4060.80                 1410.00
Валик                  2019-02-25              Электро          172.50                  172.50
Валик                  2019-05-08              Электро          182.00                  182.00
```

И много еще других позиций.

Я посчитал отклонение в цене конкретного материала (`СубконтоДт1`) следующим образом:

```
df['Цена'] = df['Сумма'] / df['Количество']

x = df.loc[['Поддон 1250*2500'], ['Период', 'СубконтоКт1', 'Цена']]
x1 = x.nlargest(1, 'Цена')
x2 = x.nsmallest(1, 'Цена')
x['Процент отклонения'] = (x1['Цена'] - x2['Цена']) / (x2['Цена'] / 100)
pd.set_option('display.precision', 2)
x

СубконтоДт1            Период         СубконтоКт1        Цена     Процент отклонения
Поддон 1250*2500     2018-09-25       СтальСоюз ПК      550.85    10.77
Поддон 1250*2500     2019-06-21       СтальСоюз ПК      541.67    10.77
Поддон 1250*2500     2019-06-08       СтальСоюз ПК      541.67    10.77
Поддон 1250*2500     2019-02-12       СтальСоюз ПК      600.00    10.77
```

Хотел бы получить на основании первой таблицы следующее:

```
СубконтоДт1              СубконтоКт1        Процент отклонения

Утеплитель               ФОРПОСТ            12 %


Валик                    Электро            11%



Поддон 1250*2500        СтальСоюз ПК        10.77%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
res = (df
       .groupby(["СубконтоДт1", "СубконтоДт1.1"])["Цена"]
       .agg(lambda x: (x.max()-x.min())/x.min()*100)
       .reset_index())
```

---

результат:

```
In [22]: res
Out[22]:
  СубконтоДт1 СубконтоДт1.1       Цена
0       Валик       Электро   5.507246
1  Утеплитель       ФОРПОСТ  25.380142
```

Comment: А не подскажите, в столбике Цена отображение такое выводит:  0.00e+00. Как можно исправить? И переименовать столбик Цена как можно? Просто отдельной строй?

Comment: @VladVladov, это так 0 отображается

Comment: 4.52e-04 - а эта цифра?

Comment: подскажите, а как вывести в нормальном виде?

Comment: `4.52 * 10^(-4)`

Comment: подозреваю это результат `pd.set_option('display.precision', 2)`